# Number Theory - Same remainder no division by multiple numbers

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How many natural numbers divide 2500, 4250 and 6700 leaving the same remainder in each case?

My approach to this question was

2500 = N.f1 + r
4250 = N.f2 + r
6700 = N.f3 + r

Hence N has to be a multiple of (6700 - 4250) , (6700-2500), and (4250-2500)

Hence, N should be a multiple of 2940 (LCM of the above mentioned numbers)

I'm stuck here.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Think about the path you are on: $10$ satisfies this property and is not a multiple of $2940$.

We are looking for values of $n$ for which $2500\equiv 4250$ and $4250\equiv 6700$ mod $n$.

The first congruency implies $n|1750$, and the second implies $n|2450$. Thus $n|2450-1750$ or $n|700$.

There are only $18$ divisors of $700$, so you should be able to check them all.

Answer (score 0):

I'd made a mistake

The approach leads to the fact that N has to be a factor of 1750 , 2450 and 4200

That means 350 is the largest value that N can take(HCF of the above mentioned numbers)

Since 350 has 12 factors, 12 is the answer